# Access an external jar file in Java

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I'm trying to access a specific class from an external jar library.
I have configured the path in my properties file

`test-library = file:/Users/test.user/test/library.jar`

`test-library2 = file:/Users/test.user/test/library2.jar`

Then I try to access it from the code but I get ClassNotFoundErrorException or IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute when I modify the path as follows

`test-library = /Users/test.user/test/library.jar`

`test-library2 = /Users/test.user/test/library2.jar`

When I locate the jar files in the resources folder and specify the path as follows **it works fine.**

`test-library = classpath:library/library.jar`

`test-library2 = classpath:library/library2.jar`

However I need to access the jar files because when the code is deployed we cannot have the jar files in the resource folder but in an external location.

**What is the correct way to specify the path of the external jar files so java could find the classes I need?**

This is the code where I'm invoking the external libraries and as I said before it works fine if the jar files are in the resource folder but I need to access the jar files from an external location in the machine.

````
@Value("${test-library}")
String library;

@Value("${test-library2}")
String library2;

  
public String testMethod(String text1, String text2) {
 try {
   log.info("[testMethod] start process");

   URLClassLoader urlClassLoader =
          new URLClassLoader(
              new URL[] {URI.create(library).toURL(), URI.create(library2).toURL()},
              this.getClass().getClassLoader());

      Class<?> classInstance = Class.forName("pro.test.service.TestService", true, urlClassLoader);
      
      Method getInstanceMethod = classInstance.getMethod("getInstance", String.class, String.class);

      Object instance = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null, data1, data2);

      Method libraryMethod = classInstance.getMethod("libraryMethod", String.class, String.class);

      log.info("[testMethod] end process");

      return (String) libraryMethod.invoke(instance, text1, text2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error testing library method: ", e);
      throw e;
    }
  }```
````

Comment: No it isn't :(  'Cause the devops tool we use copy the jar files outside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) of `URLClassLoader` we find:

> This class loader is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both JAR files and directories. Any `jar:` scheme URL (see [JarURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/JarURLConnection.html)) is assumed to refer to a JAR file.

and following the above [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) to `JarURLConnection`:

> The syntax of a JAR URL is:
>
> `jar:<url>!/{entry}`
>
> . . . If the entry name is omitted, the URL refers to the whole JAR file: `jar:http://www.example.com/bar/baz.jar!/` **¹**

Putting these together, we get, for the first JAR posted in question:

`jar:file:/Users/test.user/test/library.jar!/`

---

<sub>**1** address changed from `foo` to `example` since the first is not accepted by StackOverflow (apparently even not inside a quoted code)</sub>